# How to get ID in each item in the listview item is from the database

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

This is my code in my activity

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.patient_list);

            try{

                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                displaypatientinfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_patientlist);
                mydb  = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                sqLiteDatabase = mydb.getReadableDatabase();
                String selection = "pat_type=? OR pat_type=? AND is_active=?";
                String[] selectionargs = {"Infant","Mother","1"};
                cursor  = mydb.getallpatient(sqLiteDatabase,selection,selectionargs);
                listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(this, R.layout.resource_patientlist);
                displaypatientinfo.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        String id, firstname, middlename, lastname, birthdate;
                        id = cursor.getString(0);`enter code here`
                        firstname = cursor.getString(1);
                        middlename = cursor.getString(2);
                        lastname = cursor.getString(3);
                        birthdate = cursor.getString(4);
                        DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(id, firstname, middlename, lastname, birthdate);
                        listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }else{


                }

       displaypatientinfo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
 public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {
                       // just wanna ask your help here that if the user click item on listview it will return the id from the database 



                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

This is my code in my List Adapter

```
package com.example.asus.wombapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.asus.wombapp.onclicklistener.PatientList_Listener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by asus on 11/04/2018.
 */

public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;

    List list = new ArrayList();

    public ListDataAdapter( Context context, int resource) {

        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
    }




    static class LayoutHandler
    {
        TextView id, name, birthdate;
        ImageView patientimage,edit,delete;

    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object){
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){

        return list.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ImageView delete;
        View row = ConvertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        DataProvider dataprovider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        if(row  == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row  = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.resource_patientlist,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            final PatientList patientList = new PatientList();
            layoutHandler.id = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
            layoutHandler.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_patientname);
            layoutHandler.birthdate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_actualbirthdate);
            layoutHandler.patientimage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image_patient);
            layoutHandler.edit = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image_edit);
            layoutHandler.delete = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image_delete);
            layoutHandler.delete.setOnClickListener(new PatientList_Listener(this.context,dataprovider.getId()));
            layoutHandler.edit.setOnClickListener(new PatientList_Listener(this.context,dataprovider.getId()));
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }else{
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag();
        }
        //set value from database to resourceview

        layoutHandler.id.setText(dataprovider.getId());
        layoutHandler.name.setText(dataprovider.getFirtsname() + " " + dataprovider.getMiddlename() +" " + dataprovider.getLastname());
        layoutHandler.birthdate.setText(dataprovider.getBirthdate());
        layoutHandler.patientimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture);
        layoutHandler.delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete_data);
        layoutHandler.edit.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit_data);

        return row;
    }

}
```

Hope you can help be in my activity i have a listview wherein all the data is from the database i just wanna ask your help how to get ID of the item on the listview. once the user click item on the listview  i can get the primary key of that item please help me the id that iam trying to get is the dataprovider.getId() in the listAdapter please hope anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
((DataProvider)listDataAdapter.getItem(position)).getId();
```

Comment: thank you very much working for it for 5 hours but this is the solution thank you so much

Comment: @NiñoCuenco glad I could help ;)

Comment: yah appreciated brother thank you so much.hope to see you soon to thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, get the listDataAdapter to return the DataProvider by position and then get its Id like this:

```
displaypatientinfo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {

        String id = listDataAdapter.get(position).getId();

    }
});
```